# Generating dictionaries that are permutations of larger dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, permutation

I don't know if the title I gave does a good job of explaining what I need my program to do. I will have dictionaries of the form:

```
main_dictionary = {1: [ [a], [b], [c], ... ], 2: [ [a], [b], [c], ... ] , ... }
```

The dictionary can be arbitrarily long and have an arbitrary number of options for each key. I need the program to then make every permutation of this dictionary to test.

```
sub_dictionary = {1: [a], 2: [a], ... }

test_program(sub_dictionary)

sub_dictionary = {1: [a], 2: [b], ... }

test_program(sub_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `itertools.product`. The result is a list of "sub-dictionaries".

For simplicity, I have used a list of integers as values, but this can be replaced by values of your choice.

```
from itertools import product

d = {1: [3, 4, 5], 2: [6, 7, 8]}

values = list(zip(*sorted(d.items())))[1]

res = [dict(enumerate(x, 1)) for x in product(*values)]
```

If you need to test each dictionary individually, use a generator expression instead and iterate it:

```
for item in (dict(enumerate(x, 1)) for x in product(*values)):
    ...
```

If you have string keys:

```
res = [dict(zip(sorted(d), x)) for x in product(*values)]
```

Result:

```
[{1: 3, 2: 6},
 {1: 3, 2: 7},
 {1: 3, 2: 8},
 {1: 4, 2: 6},
 {1: 4, 2: 7},
 {1: 4, 2: 8},
 {1: 5, 2: 6},
 {1: 5, 2: 7},
 {1: 5, 2: 8}]
```

Comment: I should have specified, the keys are specific names. how would I adjust this to get: {key1: 3,key2:6}?